How to programmatically select item from DropdownButton

Update: Following @CBroe's advice, I was able to solve it with document.getElementById('tux-2_list_1').click()! :D


Update 2: But it turns out this only worked if I clicked on the item within Inspect Element first. It will say TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click') if I reload the form. I tried using document.getElementById('').focus() on tux-2_list_1, tux-2_button and 'tux-2_list but just got TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'focus').


Update 3: Solved by using document.getElementById('tux-2_button').click() followed by document.getElementById('tux-2_list_1').click()!

document.getElementById('tux-2_button').selectedIndex = [...document.getElementById('tux-2_button').options].findIndex (option => option.text === "I’d like to report a possible copyright infringement in user-generated content") returns TypeError: document.getElementById.options is not iterable.
Testing with document.getElementById('tux-2_button').value returns '' no matter what option is selected.
document.getElementById('tux-2_button').textContent = "I’d like to report a possible copyright infringement in user-generated content" changes the button text but does not trigger the event.
The DropdownButton does have an ID ('tux-2_button'):
<button type="button" id="tux-2_button" aria-labelledby="tux-2_label tux-2_button" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-controls="tux-2_list" aria-expanded="false" aria-invalid="false" class="css-1hneche">
  <div class="css-157g8iw">Select</div>
  <div class="css-40sddq"></div>

  <svg fill="currentColor" class="css-fdovmm" viewBox="0 0 48 48" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1em" height="1em">
    <path d="M24.71 32.03a1 1 0 0 1-1.58 0L14.4 20.6a1 1 0 0 1 .8-1.61h17.54a1 1 0 0 1 .79 1.61l-8.82 11.42Z"></path>
  </svg>
</button>

Here are the selection options that are linked:
<ul id="tux-2_list" role="listbox" aria-labelledby="tux-2_label" tabindex="-1" class="css-9zaeqv">
  <li id="tux-2_list_1" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-list-item-value="1" class="css-1o2kt1p"><span>I’d like to report a possible copyright infringement in user-generated content</span></li>
  <li id="tux-2_list_2" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-list-item-value="2" class="css-1o2kt1p"><span>Reporting a possible copyright infringement in advertisements or TikTok Shop</span></li>
  <li id="tux-2_list_3" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-list-item-value="3" class="css-1o2kt1p"><span>Reporting a possible trademark infringement in user-generated content</span></li>
  <li id="tux-2_list_4" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-list-item-value="4" class="css-1o2kt1p"><span>Found inappropriate content on TikTok</span></li>
  <li id="tux-2_list_5" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-list-item-value="5" class="css-1o2kt1p"><span>Someone is impersonating me, sharing my private information, or featuring me in content on TikTok without my consent</span></li>
  <li id="tux-2_list_6" role="option" aria-selected="false" data-list-item-value="6" class="css-1o2kt1p"><span>None of the above</span></li>
</ul>

I tried interacting with 'tux-2_list' too. Is my issue that I need to find the correct ID to interact with? Do you have some advice on how I can solve this? You can find the live HTML page linked here if you find it helpful.

You are trying to treat a button as if it was a select here, which does not make sense to begin with. A select field does have properties like selectedIndex and options - a button does not.

@CBroe Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that I tried interacting with 'tux-2_list' too. I guess my problem is I do not find the right ID I am supposed to interact with?

Couldn't say, don't know how you tried to "interact" with it. But I doubt that you will be able to handle this like a normal select element in any way. This is a custom-build control, probably with event handlers attached to provide the functionality. Triggering a click event on the "option" you want to select, is what I'd try first (without having further analyzed how exactly their component works.)

Thank you sooooo much, that click did the trick!

Newer mind about the UI (all the HTML that you present), the interesting thing is what key/value does the form submit contain. So, when picking an item from the list, what happens? Is there a hidden input element that is updated, or is there a variable or a property of an object that is updated?

Thanks for reply @chrwahl, it worked to .click() like CBroe suggested. :D

To add the other comments: having <div> elements inside a button would make for invalid HTML. The only content allowed in a button is "phrasing content". Looking at that list: <div> isn't allowed but <svg> is.

@Andy thanks, I didn't make the website so I don't know why that is there :c

The problem is straightforward. There are two issues here.
Firstly, "TypeError: document.getElementById.options is not iterable"
This error message suggests that the options property is not iterable. To fix this, you should access the options property directly on the element, not on the "getElementById" result. I might do this:
[document.getElementById('tux-button').getElementsByTagName('option')].findIndex(option => option.text === "I’d like to report a possible copyright infringement in user-generated content")

Secondly, document.getElementById(‘tux-2_button’).value returns ‘’ no matter what option is selected:
The value property of a dropdown element represents the value of the selected option, not the text content. If you want to set the selected option, use the selectedIndex property instead.
For instance,
// Selects the first option
document.getElementById('tux-2_button').selectedIndex = 1; 

Finally, I might implement it like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dropdown Selection Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="tux-2_button">
        <option value="1">I’d like to report a possible copyright infringement in user-generated content</option>
        <option value="2">Reporting a possible copyright infringement in advertisements or TikTok Shop</option>
        <!-- Add other options here -->
    </select>

    <!-- Other form elements go here -->

    <script>
        // Get the dropdown element
        const dropdown = document.getElementById('tux-2_button');

        // Set the desired option (e.g., select the second option)
        dropdown.selectedIndex = 1;

        // Simulate a click event (if needed)
        // dropdown.click();

        // Add event listener to handle selection changes
        dropdown.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const selectedOption =   event.target.options[event.target.selectedIndex];
        console.log(`Selected option: ${selectedOption.text} (Value: ${selectedOption.value})`);
        // Handle your logic here
        });
    </script>
</body>

Does that sound like a good idea?

Thank you very much :) I did try the ".selectedIndex = 1" parts too and all they did was return 1 in the console, but I managed to solve it now by using .click() directly on the desired item!
